# Location biasing or limiting by US State in Google Autocomplete

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, google-places

I am trying to limit Google Autocomplete to a single state. From what I see in Google's documentation, restricting is only available by country. However, can biasing be done?
I don't really have code to show because it's an API question.
I do see that it is possible to use `strictbounds` and am even considering finding some JSON with lat/lng data for all states, and using that. But trying here first.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the `Places Autocomplete API`, there are ways to [bias the results and also restrict the location](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#location_biasing) you want the API to return with a certain level of granularity.

You may want to check the [`GeocoderComponentRestrictions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geocoder#GeocoderComponentRestrictions) interface as well and consider component restriction to administrative areas, postal code and more.